# In an apocalyptic situation, where would a person be able to find a prosthetic?

Tags: apocalypse, zombies, medical

If the zombie apocalypse were to happen, in what places would a survivor be able to find an artificial leg for a person missing it.

Comment: To be honest, 'people who need prosthetics' sound like 'people who got eaten by zombies.'

Answer (score 5):

I know this will be disappointing, but likely in the same places modern/current amputees do. Search hospitals, medical supply stores, and VA clinics.

Finding one that fits well will be a challenge, most are custom made these days, but the pre-apocalypse sources are still your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

Off of a limping zombie?

Start with the yellow pages to find out if you are lucky enough to live in a town where such prosthetics are manufactured.  Barring that, look for durable medical equipment providers, again in the yellow pages.

If all else fails, find another survivor with some wood working skills and bribe them to make a simple one.

Answer (score 1):

Prosthetists are stand alone businesses.

http://www.hanger.com/Pages/default.aspx

They build, customize and repair prostheses.  There will be more prostheses  available at one of these sites than anywhere else.  There might even be equipment and spare parts to help with the fit.

Comment: Is your first sentence a deliberate pun?  Doesn't matter, I would consider a re-phrase, as it might come across as crass.